# spring boot jar doesn't work in ec2 server

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, spring-boot

In localhost my app works, but in ec2 after run I have error 404. I saw other answers and added in my application.properties `server.context-path=/index` and in my Application

```
@Bean
    public DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet (){
        return new DispatcherServlet();
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean dispatchServletRegistration(){
        ServletRegistrationBean registrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(dispatcherServlet(), "/*");
        registrationBean.setName(DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.DEFAULT_DISPATCHER_SERVLET_REGISTRATION_BEAN_NAME);
        return registrationBean;
    }
```

But still doesn't work. What I do wrong?

Comment: do you get any errors at startup?

Comment: did you update your security group of the EC2 instance ? so you allow traffic on the port where the app is running

Comment: only 404 error, but, when I prescribe the full path like url-address/static/index.html it's work.